# Can "normal" Hermetic Magi take virtues from Realms of Power: Magic?

Tags: ars-magica-5

Page 43 of Realms of Power: Magic starts a list of new Virtues & Flaws for "when designing magic characters or characters that are somehow associated with the realm of Magic".  Hermetic magi are usually taken to be associated with the realm of Magic, so are they permitted to take these virtues and flaws?

Some of the virtues and flaws are clearly only appropriate for Magical Companions; but others, particularly the Hermetic ones, seem to be appropriate for any magi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beginning of the chapter that you are referring to, RoPM page 29, says that those rules, including the Virtues and Flaws, are for magical characters who have a Magical Might Score.

Since most magi are "merely aligned with the realm of Magic" they would **not be permitted** to take those virtues and flaws. However, it does state that characters with the Transformed (Being) Virtue would have a Magical Might Score and would be able to take other virtues and flaws from the chapter.

Comment: This is incorrect, RoP: Magic *defines* what a Magic Character is on page 29, but it does not say that the Virtues and Flaws listed are only appropriate for Magic Characters. In fact, the Virtues granting Powers have different rules than the equivalent Qualities "since the character does not have a Might Score."